# I want to disable "guest checkout is disabled" message

Tags: magento2.3

I want to disable "guest checkout is disabled" warning on cart page. How can i this?

Comment: check and let me know it's working for you or not

Comment: I will try but it seems not ok.

Comment: what you seems not ok? as you asked in question i have added notice on cart page.

Comment: By default the notice already show on cart page I want to turn off that notice.

Comment: Ohh sorry i understood totally wrong. i checked but not getting any notice there

Comment: Please disable guest checkout on admin before check

Comment: answer updated check

Answer (score 1):

Create `di.xml` file under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

and use the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Index"/>
</config>
```

Create `Index.php` file under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

and use the code below

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index
{
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper */
        $checkoutHelper = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data::class);
        if (!$checkoutHelper->canOnepageCheckout()) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('One-page checkout is turned off.'));
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }

        $quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
        if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError() || !$quote->validateMinimumAmount()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }

        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && !$checkoutHelper->isAllowedGuestCheckout($quote)) {
            // $this->messageManager->addError(__('Guest checkout is disabled.'));
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }

        // generate session ID only if connection is unsecure according to issues in session_regenerate_id function.
        // @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php
        if (!$this->isSecureRequest()) {
            $this->_customerSession->regenerateId();
        }
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->setCartWasUpdated(false);
        $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Checkout'));
        return $resultPage;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if current request uses SSL and referer also is secure.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isSecureRequest(): bool
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $referrer = $request->getHeader('referer');
        $secure = false;

        if ($referrer) {
            $scheme = parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
            $secure = $scheme === 'https';
        }

        return $secure && $request->isSecure();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!